# Facing issue while publishing apps to odoo.com site

Tags: odoo

I have a git hub account and I am created a repository in it. I need to publish this module in odoo.com site.

I have registered the repository in the site but on clicking 'Publish' button I am not able to see the app in the Registered app list.

Comment: Hi @anitha can please add the link to your GitHub repository

Comment: The issue was in the manifest file. When I corrected it the app worked properly. Thank you.